# Getting the getElementId Dynamically from HTML

Tags: javascript, html

So I am writing a Js script that accepts a number of rows and number of columns from the HTML. This will generate an HTML template for the customer using for loops . A customer should have the ability to select a product that features on the HTML template. this will take up 2 columns on the template instead of one.

The way I am trying to allow the customer to choose where the featured product displays a table.

```
function featProdDisplay(column, row) {
  let body;

  body = `<table style = "border-collapse: collapse;">`;

  for (let i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    body += `<tr>`

    for (let j = 0; j < column; j++) {
      pos = Number(i) + Number(j);
      body += `<td id = "` + pos + `onclick="Selected()">
            <div>
            </div>
            </td>`
    };
    body += `</tr>`
  };

  body += `</table>`;
  
  return body;
}

function DisplayTable(column, row) {
  body = featProdDisplay(column, row);
  document.getElementById("FeatDisplay").innerHTML = body;
}
```

[image: an example of the selection table]

The way i was thinking is that the customer clicks on a block and drags it down to where the he/she would like it to end. those s will then change color.

So my question is is there any way to get the position or IDs of those s that have been selected as the ID is generated Dynamically and getElementById() requires a preexisting ID? Or should I try a different approach entirely?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What mechanism are you using for drag? That would normally have a property or callback to return the element.

Comment: Before everything else, you should change id generation logic. Because 2 + 2 and 1 + 3 and 3 + 1 etc will create the same id. Instead of that use row_i_col_j or data attributes.

Comment: Don't use `id` with numbers at all. The click handler can easily derive what the coordinates are. There is no need for such `id` attributes. It is an antipattern.

Comment: In addition to the above comments, why are you using template strings with `+`? The whole point of template strings is that you _don't_ need string concatenation. ```body = `${body}<td id="${pos} .....`; ```. And to take that one step further: if you're building the content this way anyway, build real dom nodes, and then `append` those, instead of constructing a string and then setting an innerHTML at the end.

Comment: There is a lot in this code that is subject for improvement. I feel the question is too broad. There is no attempt at implementing a drag feature.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Apologies for the issues in the code. I only started with JS a month ago so I don't fully know what i am doing yet. But i will look at the issues raised.

Comment: @isherwood I don't have a mechanism in mind yet, I guess i was first trying to figure out how to Id different tds without a static id